# Delete the respective row completely if acutal quantity goes to zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, erb

I want to delete the respective row completely if `tquantity = 0`.

Find the screenshot for better understanding as below;

[screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCLFF.png)

index.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table class="table listing text-center">
                <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
                    <td>COLOR</td>
                    <td>QUANTITY</td>
                    <td>RETAIL PRICE</td>
                    <td>TOTAL AMOUNT</td>
                    <td>CARTON NO</td>
                    <td>CUSTOMER 1</td>
                    <td>CUSTOMER 2</td>
                    <td>ACTUAL QUANTITY</td>
                </tr>

                <% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>

                <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.description %></td>
                    <td class="col-1"><%= purchase.color %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.quantity %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.rprice, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>        
                    <td class="col-2"><%= number_with_precision(purchase.tamount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>  
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cartonno %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus1 %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= purchase.cus2 %></td>
                    <td class="col-2"><%= tquantity = purchase.quantity - purchase.cus1 - purchase.cus2 %></td>

                </tr>

                <% end %>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

purchases_controller.rb

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_purchase, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /Stockings
  # GET /deldetails.json
  def index
    #@purchases = Purchase.all
    @purchases = Purchase.where("tquantity !=?", 0)
  end

  def import
    Purchase.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to purchases_url, notice: "Purchases imported."
  end

  # GET /purchases/1
  # GET /purchases/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /purchases/new
  def new
    @purchase = Purchase.new
  end

  # GET /purchases/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /purchases
  # POST /purchases.json
  def create
    @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @purchase.save
        format.html { redirect_to @purchase, notice: 'Purchase was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @purchase }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @purchase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /purchases/1
  # PATCH/PUT /purchases/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @purchase.update(purchase_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @purchase, notice: 'Purchase was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @purchase }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @purchase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /purchases/1
  # DELETE /purchases/1.json
  def destroy
    @purchase.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to purchases_url, notice: 'Purchase was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_purchase
      @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def purchase_params
      params.require(:purchase).permit(:season, :category, :articleno, :description, :color, :quantity, :rprice, :tamount, :cartonno, :cus1, :cus2, :tquantity )
    end
end
```

purchase.rb

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Purchase.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end
end
```

Do I need to use SQL WHERE clause, and if yes, then how would I obtain the desired result?

Comment: When you say that you want to "delete the respective row completely if tquantity = 0", does this mean deleting the row from the database, or just from the view that you showed in the screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to know both the aspects.

Comment: Is anythig wrong with this particular coding which is, <td class="col-2"><%= tquantity = purchase.quantity - purchase.cus1 - purchase.cus2 %></td> , as the Purchase.first.tquantity in the rails console show nil values for all the purchases.

Comment: Is tquantity a column in your purchase table?

Comment: Yes , tquantity is a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `update` action, you'll want to check to see if the new values cause the purchase to match the deletion criteria that you set.  Use these changes to the `update` action to make that happen:

```
# PATCH/PUT /purchases/1
# PATCH/PUT /purchases/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    updated = @purchase.update(purchase_params)
    deleted = (@purchase.quantity - @purchase.cus1 - @purchase.cus2) <= 0
    if deleted
      @purchase.destroy
      format.html { redirect_to purchases_url, notice: 'Purchase was deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    elsif updated
      format.html { redirect_to @purchase, notice: 'Purchase was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @purchase }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @purchase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Regarding the view, in case there happen to be any rows that should be filtered in the data, you can use this query:

```
# GET /Stockings
# GET /deldetails.json
def index
  @purchases = Purchase.where("quantity - cus1 - cus2 > 0") # Only records with a valid total quantity
end
```

For the CSV import, the values can be filtered prior to creating the Purchase model object.  Try changing to use this:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    if (row["quantity"].to_i - row["cus1"].to_i - row["cus2"].to_i) > 0
      Purchase.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

This will eliminate any invalid (zero quantity) Purchase model objects from being created in the application during the CSV import process.  This assumes that the header fields are named "quantity", "cus1", and "cus2", and may need to be adjusted slightly to match the actual header field names.

Comment: Excellent! Right now when I am importing csv file it gives me values greater than zero hiding zero values, but if I want to delete those zero values completely how do I proceed?

Comment: It all depends on how you're importing CSV, I suppose.  The `update` action will delete them, but if you have a separate CSV import, you would have to either pre-filter the zero value records or destroy them after the import.  Pre-filtering will be much faster, and might make a significant performance difference if you have a lot of records and a significant number of records to be deleted.  If you include the details of your CSV import into your question, I'll see if I can include the filtering in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I have update my question with purchase.rb file.

Comment: Sir, I would like to pre-filter the zero value records and destroy them after the import. Hope you understand the matter.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen I have updated my answer to include the CSV import.

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting this error while importing which is, undefined method `-' for "15":String and my fields are as follows;                       2.2.0 :003 > Purchase
 => Purchase(id: integer, season: string, category: string, articleno: string, description: string, color: string, quantity: integer, rprice: decimal, tamount: decimal, cartonno: integer, cus1: integer, cus2: integer, tquantity: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Comment: I updated the CSV filter, and the code will now convert the fields to integer values.  There's another way to do it, as well, but it may slow the program down and could introduce other issues if the data isn't strictly normalized.  So, I went with the easy, direct solution.

Comment: Great Job! Thank you very much.It's all working fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and worked around it using `destroy_all` rather than `destroy`. This cleared the row from showing up for me. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is when in run the code which is @purchases = Purchase.where("tquantity !=?", 0) in controller/index it doesn't show up anything on the screen.